# Velocity boundary conditions from water depth time series

Tags: oceanography, models, ocean-currents, tides, ocean-models

Currently, I am setting up a hydrodynamic model for a coastal zone. For this purpose I need to impose the velocity and water level at the open boundary.

Tidal models (e.g. TPXO) can give both velocity (U, V) and water depth. But, if the water depth time series is measured over time, how can we derive the velocity (U, V) from it?